# How to obtain the Base64 representation of a string in Android Oreo

Tags: java, android, base64

I need to convert string into base64 under Oreo api level.
I have the following code:

```
 public String genAuthKey(String u, String p){
    user = u;
    pass = p;
    key = user+":"+pass;
    byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[0];
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(key.getBytes());
        Log.e("VERSION IS","O");

    }else{
        encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getBytes()).getBytes();
        Log.e("VERSION LESS","O");
    }
    Log.e("key",new String(encodedBytes,Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    return new String(encodedBytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

}
```

In else condition, I need code to convert and send the data properly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first add this import

```
import android.util.Base64;
```

then replace your method with a version agnostic variant

```
public String genAuthKey(String u, String p) {
        user = u;
        pass = p;
        key = user + ":" + pass;
        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encode(key.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.e("key", new String(encodedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return new String(encodedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
```

Enjoy!

Comment: E/Genrate: Unexpected char 0x0a at 26 in Authorization value: BASIC MTM5ODphbnVqMTIzNA==

Comment: @AnujVaish I'm sure your error is not associated with encoding to base64 because this code I posted works on Android Q

Comment: i want use import java.util.Base64 not android.util.Base64 and its should support under android version O

Comment: @AnujVaish Why don't you want to use the classes from the android namespace. In android development, classes from the android.* packages are preferred because they are usually optimized for mobile devices. Mind you, Java existed before Android, the developers didn't consider mobile optimizations when developing the JDK. That is why we have optimized versions of some Java libraries in android

Comment: Because Backend Developer match with java,util.Base64 and android.util.Base64 not matched, i will pass this msg to backend team they should convert from java to android packages.

Answer (score -3):

Try this code for encoding kotlin:

```
var encodedString = Base64.encode("Your String", Base64.DEFAULT).toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
```

and for decoding:

```
var decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT).toString(Charsets.UTF_8)
```